# Replacing ] with ]) when it appears after $_GET[

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Long story short I'd like to wrap 6.5k `$_GET['arbitrarystring']` with `()` so it becomes `($_GET['arbitrarystring'])`

I can find and replace `$_GET[` with `($_GET[` easily enough. I don't however want to replace any arbitrary `']` with `'])` just those that follow `$_GET['arbitrarystring`

How could I accomplish this? Assume there's a valid reason for doing so.

Comment: 1. Do you have `$_GET['arbitrarystring']` as a string ?!? 2. Please show your current code 3. Also show an example with the input and expected output

Comment: Uh.. No, $_GET['arbitrarystring'] is quite literally the current code. Looking to do this using find/replace across 1100 files.

Comment: What IDE/file editor are you using? What operating platform? Or do you want a PHP script that will recurse over files/folders doing it?

Comment: Atom on OS X. It supports both regular and regex find/replace

Comment: No results found on that one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP using `preg_replace`:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\$_GET\[\'[^\']+\'\]/', '($0)', $string);
```

To use it in an IDE or other tool the pattern would be:

`\$_GET\['[^']+'\]`

Then use whatever the match back-reference is in your IDE surrounded by `()` as replacement.

Comment: This seems like it would work on a string. It does select any given $_GET['arbitrarystring'].